# How to extract specific link within a div?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a `soup` with content like following many `<div>`, those who I'm interested in are which have the class `foo`

In each `<div>`, there are a lot of links and other content, I'm interested in the second link (second `<a> </a>`) => **it is always the second**.

I want to grab the value of `href` attribute and the text between the second link tag `<a> </a>`

for example :

```
<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example2.com"> Title here </a>
</div>

<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example3.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example4.com"> Title 2 here </a>
</div>
```

here I want to get :

Title here => http://example2.com

Title 2 here => http://example4.com

I've tried writing some code :

```
soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "foo" })
```

but that returns a list with all divs and their content and I don't know how to go further

thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterate `div`s and find `a` there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = '''
<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example2.com"> Title here </a>
</div>

<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example3.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example4.com"> Title 2 here </a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'foo'}):
    a = div.findAll('a')[1]
    print a.text.strip(), '=>', a.attrs['href']
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Times change and new versions of `BeautifulSoup`come out

> As of version 4.7.0, Beautiful Soup supports most CSS4 selectors via the SoupSieve project.

So you can alternatively use [`css-selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) like `:nth-of-type(2)` to get all expected elements as `dict` with text and `href` value:

```
dict((a.text,a.get('href')) for a in soup.select('div.foo a:nth-of-type(2)'))
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example2.com"> Title here </a>
</div>

<div class ="foo">
     <a href ="http://example3.com"> </a>
     <a href ="http://example4.com"> Title 2 here </a>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

dict((a.text,a.get('href')) for a in soup.select('div.foo a:nth-of-type(2)'))
```

##### Output

```
{' Title here ': 'http://example2.com',
 ' Title 2 here ': 'http://example4.com'}
```