# How to scrape data from specific child of an element?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello this is a dummy code but I want to get the Doodle text from the second `<a>`:

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="www.google.com"></a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles"> Doodle </a>
</div>
```

These are my failed codes:

```
soup.find('div', {'class' : 'test'}) #1
soup.find('div', {'class' : 'test'}).next_sibling #2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beautifulsoup - extracting link within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763542/beautifulsoup-extracting-link-within-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

```
doodletext = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'test'})
print(doodletext.text)
```

This will work only for this example. If you need to find `Doodle` and there are other text around, you may need to use the `split()` function to drill down the specific string of text you are looking for.

Comment: Okay so if there's another text within the first a tag, we should use split() and search the specific string, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

Check this question: [beautifulsoup - extracting link within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763542/beautifulsoup-extracting-link-within-a-div)

And try this:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'test'}):
    a = div.find_all('a')[1]
    print(a.text.strip())
```

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to get your goal, essential is as always the pattern or structure you have to work with.

Assuming that the `<a>` is still the second, you could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) like `:nth-of-type(2)`:

```
soup.select_one('div.test a:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
#Doodle
```

Assuming it is always the last one you could also use the index of your `ResultSet`:

```
soup.find('div', {'class' : 'test'}).find_all('a')[-1].get_text(strip=True)  
#Doodle
```

or again alternative with `css selectors` for last one:

```
soup.select_one('div.test a:last-of-type').get_text(strip=True)
#Doodle

soup.select('div.test a')[-1].get_text(strip=True)
#Doodle
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="test">
    <a href="www.google.com"></a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles"> Doodle </a>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.select_one('div.test a:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True))

print(soup.find('div', {'class' : 'test'}).find_all('a')[-1].get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Output for both

```
Doodle
```